# Changing section colors: Undefined control sequence. \sectionfont

Tags: color, titlesec, sectsty

I know there are several questions with answers out there, but none of them worked for me.

Trying to change the color of all sections of my document with the `xcolor` package creates an error statement: `Undefined control sequence. \sectionfont`

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, twoside]{article}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{xcolor}
    \sectionfont{\color{red}}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{202F}{\,}
\usepackage[colorlinks,hidelinks,urlcolor=blue,bookmarks=false,hypertexnames=true]{hyperref} 

\author{Louis Vigneras}
\title{Potential and Future inequalities in the 5G Era}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
    
\end{document}
```

Anyone knows what’s going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\sectionfont` command is provided by the [sectsty](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) package, not the [titlesec](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package. To get `\sectionfont` to work, you should therefore replace the preamble instruction

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
```

with

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
```

Comment: Dang it, it was so simple. Thank you very much!